# UINavigationController's child bounds / frame?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I'm pushing a `ViewController` into a `NavigationController` without setting its `frame`.

Even though the new view is displayed below the navigation bar as expected, its bounds property shows the whole screen size minus the status bar (`{0, 0}, {320, 460}` on the iPhone), and its frame starts below the status bar, not below the navigation bar (`{0, 20}, {320, 460}`).

How can I get the actual bounds and frame from within the child's `ViewController`?

Comment: Anyone? I REALLY need a hint on this one !!! thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Examine the `bounds` in `viewWillAppear`. When this is called the bounds will be set correctly, in this case to {320, 416}, taking into account the height of the navigation bar. The bounds are not yet correctly set in `viewDidLoad`.